# Javascript, TypeError: "function" is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have this little problem... in this code if I define only start() everything works, but when I declare time(), i got the error:
"TypeError: start is not a function". Where is the problem??
Here the code,

```js
//start
function start(){
 
 //removes title and start boxes
 var body=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 var start_box=document.getElementById("start_box");
 var title_box=document.getElementById("title_box");
 body.removeChild(start_box);
 body.removeChild(title_box);
 
 //creates stats box
 var stats_box=document.createElement("div");
 stats_box.id="stats_box";
 var time=document.createElement("p");
 time.id="time";
 var points=document.createElement("p");
 points.id="points";
 stats_box.appendChild(points);
 stats_box.appendChild(time);
 body.appendChild(stats_box);
 
 //creates play box
 var play_box=document.createElement("div");
 play_box.id="play_box";
 body.appendChild(play_box);
 
}

//time
function time(){
 var time=document.getElementById("time");
 for(x=30,x>=0,x--){
  time.innerHTML("Time:"+x);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PICK 'EM ALL</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pta.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="pta.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="title_box">
   <p id="title">PICK 'EM ALL</p>
  </div>
  <div id="start_box" onclick="start()">
   <p id="start">START</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's just a typo: You've used `,` instead of `;` in the `for` in `time`, so the script as a whole doesn't parse, and nothing defined in it is created. You need `for(x=30;x>0;x--)` There are two valuable lessons here: 1. Open your web console, it's telling you exactly what's wrong. 2. A syntax error can blow up an entire script.

Comment: Your code is also falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): Declare your variables (`x`, for instance, in `time`).

Comment: For the OP, I would suggest using a good Editor with Linting built in, errors like these will then get picked up instantly.

Comment: Mistake in for loop function time(){
 var time=document.getElementById("time");
 for(x=30;x>=0;x--){
  time.innerHTML("Time:"+x);
 }
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue is with for loop, it should be semi-colon instead of comma

```
for(x=30;x>=0;x--){
        time.innerHTML("Time:"+x);
    }
```

Comment: Typos don't need answers, just comments (I've already done that) and close votes.